# how to change "\\xe4\\xbd\\xa0" to Chinese in goland

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, go

I get a string like this

```
"\\xe4\\xbd\\xa0"
```

now I want to print this string to chinese in go. like this

```
你
```

In python2.7，I can do this

```
print "\\xe4\\xbd\\xa0".decode("string-escape")
# 你
```

But I don't know how to do it.

How do I do it in go?